# jquery - ie8 and substr function not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I made a time card calculator that works fine in Chrome/FF/IE9.

For some reason I get an error on IE8 - `Error: Object doesn't support this property or method` on Line 217 which is:

```
timeIn_hrs = timeIn.substring(0,2);
```

with timeIn being:

```
timeIn = $("#timein").val();
```

a numerical value in an input.

Here is a jsFiddle of it in it's entirety: http://jsfiddle.net/m2rQw/

I am novice so any advice is appreciated.

**EDIT: Declaring them var timeIn rather than just timeIn fixed it. Thanks Wirey**

Comment: @elzi NP.. IE is very picky about everything.  Other browsers you can get away with it but you should really make it a habit to use `var` in javascript

Comment: @elzi Every variable you declare without `var` is automatically global, no matter where you declare it. Using `var` is not a "good habit", it is something you *absolutely must do every time* you declare a variable.